# Pytorch's Transformer decoder accuracy fluctuation

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model, self-attention

I have a sequence to sequence POS tagging model which uses Transformer decoder to generate target tokens.
My implementation of Pytorch's Transformer decoder is as follows:

in the initialization:

```py
    self.decoder_layer = nn.TransformerDecoderLayer(d_model=ENV_HIDDEN_SIZE, nhead=2,batch_first=True,dim_feedforward=300 ,activation="relu")
    self.transformer_decoder = nn.TransformerDecoder(self.decoder_layer, num_layers=2)
```

and in the forward function:

```py
    if infer==False: # for training
        embedded=embedded*math.sqrt(ENV_HIDDEN_SIZE)
        embedded = self.pos_encoder(embedded)
        zol = self.transformer_decoder(tgt=embedded,memory=newtensor
                                       ,memory_mask=self.transformer_mask
                                       ,memory_key_padding_mask=x_mask
                                       ,tgt_mask=self.transformer_mask)

        scores = self.slot_trans(self.dropout3(zol))
    else: #for inferrence
        bos = Variable(torch.LongTensor([[tag2index['<BOS>']]*batch_size])).cuda().transpose(1,0)
        bos = self.embedding(bos)
        tokens=bos
        for i in range(length):
            temp_embedded=tokens*math.sqrt(ENV_HIDDEN_SIZE)
            temp_embedded = self.pos_encoder(temp_embedded)
            zol = self.transformer_decoder(tgt=temp_embedded,
                                           memory=newtensor,
                                           tgt_mask=self.transformer_mask[:i+1,:i+1],
                                           memory_key_padding_mask=x_mask,
                                           memory_mask=self.transformer_mask[:i+1,:]
                                           )
            scores = self.slot_trans(self.dropout3(zol))
            softmaxed = self.softmax(scores)
            _,input = torch.max(softmaxed,2)
            newtok = self.embedding(input)
            tokens=torch.cat((bos,newtok),dim=1)
```

and the memory_mask is generated by the function "generate_square_subsequent_mask" as given:

```py
    def generate_square_subsequent_mask(sz: int) :
        """Generates an upper-triangular matrix of -inf, with zeros on diag."""
        return torch.triu(torch.ones(sz, sz) * float('-inf'), diagonal=1)
```

I am observing something weird. If I **do not** feed the memory_mask with generate_subsequent_mask  -which I should not according to [this post](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-get-memory-mask-for-nn-transformerdecoder/60414/4)-, the accuracy severely decreases. Furthermore, accuracy of the model fluctuates between 50% and 90% on each epoch randomly on the test set but not the training set.
if I **do** feed the memory_mask, everything is fine, and model accuracy steadily increases to 95% on the test set. Moreover, the final accuracy takes a hit when **not feeding** the memory_mask.
Things I tried:

1. Without memory_mask: Tuning the learning rate.
2. Without memory_mask: Increasing the nhead and num_layers.
3. Using a simple linear layer.

At the end-note, using a simple linear layer instead of the transformer decoder provides a better accuracy. Any ideas as to why this is happening?